# Starting service as non root user

Tags: bash, ubuntu, service, debian, init.d

Can someone help us understand how to properly start our programs service as the services user (marty for example).

We're using init.d to start our process (java application), but when the system(s) boot (Ubuntu and Debian) because the service script is run as root, we're having problems where the application is starting as root too and the PID file is being created by root which is messing things up.

We tried using sudo, but this is not a great solution as we dont want the sudo process running too with our application as a child process plus we need this to work on other systems that may not have sudo. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In the init script, you can check the $UID of the calling user.

If it is root, you can run the service with "runuser". If it is marty - run it directly, if it is another user - exit with error for example.

Here's some example bash (untested):

```
start() {
    if [ $UID -eq 0 ]; then
        runuser -s /bin/bash marty -c "$DAEMON start $DAEMONOPTS"
    elif [ "$USER" = "marty" ]; then
        $DAEMON start $DAEMONOPTS
    else
        print "Please run me with root or marty."
        exit 2
    fi
}
```

Same for stop and any other functions as required.

Feel free to modify the runuser command as necessary, maybe you won't need the shell for example.

Answer (score 0):

Use **start-stop-daemon**  which accepts a user name and an executable as parameters.